# Xamarin Android CardView in Visual Studio 2017 using NuGet

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, nuget, cardview

I'm trying to install Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView package via NuGet, but it fails with this error in Error list window:

```
При попытке установить необходимые компоненты Android для проекта "App1" произошла ошибка.
Для проекта "App1" на вашем компьютере должны быть установлены следующие компоненты:
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView
JavaLibraryReference: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.aar-23.4.0.0
AndroidResources: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip-m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.aar-23.4.0.0
Дважды щелкните здесь, чтобы установить их.
Ошибки установки: XA5209 Сбой распаковки. Скачайте "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip" и извлеките его в каталог
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.4.0.0\content".
XA5209 Причина: Не удалось найти часть пути "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.4.0.0\content\m2repository\".
XA5207 Установите пакет: "Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" доступен в установщике пакета SDK.. Файл библиотеки Java     "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.4.0.0\content\classes.jar" не существует.
```

Double click on this error shows a little window that is trying to dowload these packages and disappers through second and that's all, error still there. I've tried to delete AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips folder, but it didn't helped.

Comment: use Android SDK Manager and install Oero Tools and set TargetFramework to last Oero Tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set target framework to 8.1, updated all packages and install CardView, it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells us pretty explicitly, this problem occurred because of failing to unpack m2repository file (a >200MB file).

> Ошибки установки: XA5209 Сбой распаковки.
>
> Google Translate: Installation errors: XA5209 Unpacking failed.

If for some reason you exited Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio or your network slowly running when you download or unpack that zip file, that file would be damaged.

To resolve this issue, the commonly used method is to delete the root folder of the package where the error come from `(...\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView)` and all the .`zips` inside the folder (`...\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips`).

If it does't work, please try to manually download [android_m2repository_r32.zip](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip) and put it into (...\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips ) folder. VS will do the rest (including extracting and installing the file).

**Note:** In some cases you might need to rename the file into it's MD5 hash of URL. (for me VS was a little stupid and doesn't do anything unless I renamed the m2repository file to it's MD5 hash).

See [Resolving Library Installation Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors) for more details.

Comment: if I understood correct, I should use [link](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip) and get md5 from this string? and file name must be a md5 from url?

Comment: @НиколайМартынюк, Yes, you can try to download the android_m2repository_r32.zip and rename it with the corresponding MD5 has F16A3455987DBAE5783F058F19F7FCDF. Check this document for details:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors

Comment: The problem is I already have F16A3455987DBAE5783F058F19F7FCDF.zip in my AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips folder and this file is the same as dowloaded from link, so replacing it does nothing.

Comment: I tried to unpack downloaded zip into AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.4.0.0\content but got error "the action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program"

Comment: @НиколайМартынюк, I could do that on my side, after unpack that zip file, I can copy it to the `...\23.4.0.0\content` folder, make sure there is no any other process lock that file, you can restart you PC, then copy it.

Comment: Okay, I did it, but now when I'm trying to install CardView, I got new error:
http://prntscr.com/iu69js

Comment: @НиколайМартынюк, I am not a Russian, so I could not understand the error in the image clear, but it seems you are missing file in the `embedded` folder, check if you have that folder and those file in that folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167245/discussion-between---and-leo-liu-msft).